# Date role playing dimension. Compare to main date dimension

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, saiku

I'm using Mondrian, Pentaho and Saiku.

For example, in a simple warehouse for orders simplified to add only the interesting parts.

There is a order fact table with columns: date, customer id and money amount.

```
|date      |customer id|amount|
|2015-04-01|          1|    50|
|2015-04-02|          1|    20|
|2015-04-02|          2|    20|
```

There is a dimension column for customers with: customer id, name and first order date:

```
|customer id|name   |first order date|
|          1|Joe    |2015-04-01      |
|          2|Charles|2015-04-02      |
```

The date for the first order of the customers is a role playing dimension.
I want to be able to have these two measures in a Mondrian cube:

- Grouping by date and by first order date, give me the money amount. This one is OK with this data model
- For every month/week, give me the money spent by customers whose first order ever was in this month/week.

I thought as this is mainly a modelling or schema issue, that maybe it's easier without writing the schema here, but can add it to the question if necessary.

The second indicator is hard to do because it must find a way to compare if the date is the same to the main dimension date. I'm trying to solve this issue by calculated measures and MemberToStr, but I cannot find the way. Any ideas about how to proceed?